# UV Editor Problem

Tags: uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

.....Hi, guys!
Today i've started doing the city by CG Geek's tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW_djQS_N8U&t=590s).
So the problem is on 10:17, when he choose "Cube Projection" he gets this on his UV Editor[image]
.

.

And here is what I get when I use the same function:[image]

Comment: maybe U > Reset and U > Cube Unwrap again?

Comment: Still the same trouble

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/a9e4620e9b3e487986b04fefed941502

Answer (score 2):

At one point he separates the roofs from the sides of the buildings, what you can do is select one top and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Normal*, choose the top view and *Unwrap > Project from View*. Now create a second UV map, invert your selection and *Unwrap > Cube Projection*. You have 2 UV maps, you can create 2 materials, one for the tops, one for the sides, and use one UV map per material.

[image]

Comment: Big thx, gonna' try this a little later, and write if it solved my problem!

Comment: "Unwrap > Project from View"
You mean that I need to press "U", then select "Unwrap", and after this I need to press "U" again and select "Project From View"?
P.S Sorry, I'm newbie at blender :(

Comment: Yes press U (Unwrap) and choose the Project from View option